# little addon for firefox to play youtube shorts in the traditional video player

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to figure out how I can make said addon for firefox redirecting to the correct video in the traditional video player. So far I've gotten this

```
const currUrl = window.location.href;

if(currUrl.indexOf("shorts") != -1) {
    var urlSplit = currUrl.split("shorts/");
    var vidId = urlSplit[1].substring(0, 11);
    location.assign('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + vidId);
}
```

but my issue at the moment is that I can't get it to work automatically when I enter a youtube short video, instead I have to reload the page for it to work.

I tried different redirecting methods, location.assign, location.replace and location.href, alongside trying to figure out why it does not recognize the url change when i enter the video to no avail.